Modifying Expansion Order with \seq put right
I have built the below to save answers and ship them out at the end (any feedback for improving this greatly appreciated).
But (perhaps as expected), with \subsubsection{\thesectionname} in
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise_list}{+b}
    {%
    \def \sectionName {\thesectionname}
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_listcontent_seq {

        \subsubsection{\thesectionname}   
        \exp_not:N
            {
                \begin{myList}%
                    #1
                \end{myList}%
            }
        }
    {
        \begin{myList}%
            #1
        \end{myList}%
    }
    }{%
    }%

I was wishing for this to catch the 'current' section (and not to be executed as a command when invoked) so that instead of the current output:

I'd get the below desired output:

MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{questions}
\toggletrue{questions}

% Redefine \section to also store the section name
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thesectionname}{}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \renewcommand{\thesectionname}{#1}%
  \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\thesection\ #1}\par\medskip
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_listcontent_seq

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise_list}{+b}
    {%
    \def \sectionName {\thesectionname}
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_listcontent_seq {

        \subsubsection{\thesectionname}   
        \exp_not:N
            {
                \begin{myList}%
                    #1
                \end{myList}%
            }
        }
    {
        \begin{myList}%
            #1
        \end{myList}%
    }
    }{%
    }%

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myList}{}
    % set-up so that list styling can be applied once and reused (twice) in the above list since we need to print it twice, once in the \seq and once to print the actual content when invoked; if there is a cleaner way to do this, please let me know.
    {%
        \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]%
    }{%
        \end{enumerate}%
    }%

\NewDocumentCommand{\myitem}{ m m }{
    \item \iftoggle{questions}{#1}{#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printAnswers}{ }{
    \togglefalse{questions}
    \section{Answers}
    \seq_use:Nn \l_listcontent_seq {\par}
    \toggletrue{questions}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

    \section{The First Section}
        
        \begin{exercise_list}
            \myitem{qa}{sa}
            \myitem{qb}{sb}
        \end{exercise_list}


    \section{The Second Section}

        \begin{exercise_list}
            \myitem{qa2}{sa2}
            \myitem{qb2}{sb2}
        \end{exercise_list}

\printAnswers

\end{document}


try \edef \sectionName {\thesectionname}.

If you want to protect a group of tokens from expansion you need to use \exp_not:n {<stuff>}, not \exp_not:N (that one just protects the one following token, in this case it tries to protect { from expanding, which does nothing since it's not expandable anyways).

When I try:
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise_list}{+b}
    {%
    \edef \sectionName {\thesectionname}
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_listcontent_seq {

        \subsection{\sectionName}
        \exp_not:n
            {
                \begin{myList}%
                    #1
                \end{myList}%
            }
        }
    {
        \begin{myList}%
            #1
        \end{myList}%
    }
    }{%
    }%

it won't compile unfortunately; seems when answers are invoked it cannot access \sectionName

@Harry  I am afraid you will need to look again on your design decisions. start from naming things consistently. Bottoms up design in your case is probably better. a) start  \addquestion b) give it a csname and counter. Say answer1 ..answer_n. Store the names answer1, answernin a clist orseq.  Store each answer's answer in a hash,i.e, end up with \tl1` storing answer 1, etc. The l3 programming layer is ideal for this. At theplace where you want to print map over the list.

@Harry Some more suggestions. If you will want to reference them using hyperref, life gets a bit more complicated.  In this case you will want to save info in the auxiliary file. Use  \Recordproperty to do so.

You could also look at the xsim package that provides this functionalities.

You have a lot of code duplication; you also don't need toggles.
My idea is to define \myitem to do
\item \__harry_exr_item:nn {#1}{#2}

where \__harry_exr_item:nn is \use_i:nn or \use_ii:nn, depending on whether we're typesetting questions or answers.
With the following code, the sequence will eventually be
The sequence \g_harry_exr_exercises_seq contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {\subsubsection {The First Section}\__harry_exr_list:Nn \use_ii:nn {\myitem
{qa}{sa} \myitem {qb}{sb}}}
>  {\subsubsection {The Second Section}\__harry_exr_list:Nn \use_ii:nn
{\myitem {qa2}{sa2} \myitem {qb2}{sb2}}}.

whereas at “question time”, we'd do
\__harry_exr_list:Nn \use_i:nn {\myitem {qa}{sa} \myitem {qb}{sb}}}

in the first section.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% variables
\tl_new:N \g_harry_exr_sectiontitle_tl
\seq_new:N \g_harry_exr_exercises_seq

% Redefine \section to also store the section name
\NewCommandCopy{\latexsection}{\section}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m}
 {
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_harry_exr_sectiontitle_tl {#3}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \latexsection*{#3}
   }
   {
    \latexsection[#2]{#3}
   }
 }

% exercises

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise_list}{+b}
 {
  \__harry_exr_save:Vn \g_harry_exr_sectiontitle_tl {#1}
  \__harry_exr_list:Nn \use_i:nn {#1}
 }
 {}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__harry_exr_save:nn
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_harry_exr_exercises_seq
   {
    \subsubsection{#1}
    \__harry_exr_list:Nn \use_ii:nn {#2}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__harry_exr_save:nn {V}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__harry_exr_list:Nn
 {
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__harry_exr_item:nn #1
  #2
  \end{enumerate}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\myitem}{ m m }
 {
  \item \__harry_exr_item:nn {#1}{#2}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printAnswers}{ }
 {
  \section{Answers}
  \group_begin:
  \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
  \seq_use:Nn \g_harry_exr_exercises_seq {}
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{The First Section}

\begin{exercise_list}
  \myitem{qa}{sa}
  \myitem{qb}{sb}
\end{exercise_list}

\section{The Second Section}

\begin{exercise_list}
  \myitem{qa2}{sa2}
  \myitem{qb2}{sb2}
\end{exercise_list}

\printAnswers

\end{document}


You may avoid redefining \section by using nameref or hyperref.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% variables
\tl_new:N \g_harry_exr_sectiontitle_tl
\seq_new:N \g_harry_exr_exercises_seq

% exercises

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise_list}{+b}
 {
  \__harry_exr_save:vn { @currentlabelname } {#1}
  \__harry_exr_list:Nn \use_i:nn {#1}
 }
 {}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__harry_exr_save:nn
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_harry_exr_exercises_seq
   {
    \subsubsection{#1}
    \__harry_exr_list:Nn \use_ii:nn {#2}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__harry_exr_save:nn {v}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__harry_exr_list:Nn
 {
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__harry_exr_item:nn #1
  #2
  \end{enumerate}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\myitem}{ m m }
 {
  \item \__harry_exr_item:nn {#1}{#2}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printAnswers}{ }
 {
  \section{Answers}
  \group_begin:
  \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
  \seq_use:Nn \g_harry_exr_exercises_seq {}
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{The First Section}

\begin{exercise_list}
  \myitem{qa}{sa}
  \myitem{qb}{sb}
\end{exercise_list}

\section{The Second Section}

\begin{exercise_list}
  \myitem{qa2}{sa2}
  \myitem{qb2}{sb2}
\end{exercise_list}

\printAnswers

\end{document}


There is no need to redefine section to get the title name. Use the nameref package.
And expansion is easier to control if you do things in steps.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{questions}
\toggletrue{questions}

\usepackage{nameref}
\ExplSyntaxOn \makeatletter

\tl_new:N\l_harry_listcontent_tl
\seq_new:N\g_harry_listcontent_seq

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise_list}{+b}
    {%
     \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_listcontent_tl 
       {\subsection}
     \tl_put_right:No \l_harry_listcontent_tl 
      { \exp_after:wN {\@currentlabelname}      
        \begin{myList}%
                    #1
        \end{myList}
      }
    \seq_gput_right:No \g_harry_listcontent_seq {\l_harry_listcontent_tl} 
    \begin{myList}%
      #1
    \end{myList} 
    }       
    {}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myList}{}
    % set-up so that list styling can be applied once and reused (twice) in the above list since we need to print it twice, once in the \seq and once to print the actual content when invoked; if there is a cleaner way to do this, please let me know.
    {%
        \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]%
    }{%
        \end{enumerate}%
    }%

\NewDocumentCommand{\myitem}{ m m }{
    \item \iftoggle{questions}{#1}{#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printAnswers}{ }{
    \togglefalse{questions}
    \section{Answers}
    \seq_use:Nn\g_harry_listcontent_seq{}
    \toggletrue{questions}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother


\begin{document}

    \section{The First Section}
        
        \begin{exercise_list}
            \myitem{qa}{sa}
            \myitem{qb}{sb}
        \end{exercise_list}


    \section{The Second Section}

        \begin{exercise_list}
            \myitem{qa2}{sa2}
            \myitem{qb2}{sb2}
        \end{exercise_list}

\printAnswers

\end{document}


I am trying (and failing) to append the page number to the section title. How would you do that with your example?

You need to expand \thesectionname inside \l_listcontent_seq. \seq_gput_right:Nn doesn't trigger expansion, replace it with \seq_gput_right:Ne and use \exp_not:n and \exp_not:N to protects things that should not be evaluated:
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise_list}{+b}
    {%
      \seq_gput_right:Ne \l_listcontent_seq
        {
          \exp_not:N \subsection { \exp_not:V \thesectionname }
          \exp_not:n
            {
                \begin{myList}%
                    #1
                \end{myList}%
            }
        }
        {
          \begin{myList}%
            #1
          \end{myList}%
        }
    }
    {%
    }%

(Edit: I added \exp_not:V after @Ulrike Fischer and @Skillmon comments).
Full example, renaming \l_listcontent_seq with \g_Harry_listcontent_seq to follow usual conventions:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{questions}
\toggletrue{questions}

% Redefine \section to also store the section name
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thesectionname}{}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \renewcommand{\thesectionname}{#1}%
  \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\thesection\ #1}\par\medskip
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_Harry_listcontent_seq

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise_list}{+b}
    {%
      \seq_gput_right:Ne \g_Harry_listcontent_seq
        {
          \exp_not:N \subsection { \exp_not:V \thesectionname }
          \exp_not:n
            {
                \begin{myList}%
                    #1
                \end{myList}%
            }
        }
        {
          \begin{myList}%
            #1
          \end{myList}%
        }
    }
    {%
    }%

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myList}{}
    % set-up so that list styling can be applied once and reused (twice) in the above list since we need to print it twice, once in the \seq and once to print the actual content when invoked; if there is a cleaner way to do this, please let me know.
    {%
        \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]%
    }{%
        \end{enumerate}%
    }%

\NewDocumentCommand{\myitem}{ m m }{
    \item \iftoggle{questions}{#1}{#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printAnswers}{ }{
    \togglefalse{questions}
    \section{Answers}
    \seq_use:Nn \g_Harry_listcontent_seq {\par}
    \toggletrue{questions}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

    \section{The First Section}

        \begin{exercise_list}
            \myitem{qa}{sa}
            \myitem{qb}{sb}
        \end{exercise_list}


    \section{The Second Section}

        \begin{exercise_list}
            \myitem{qa2}{sa2}
            \myitem{qb2}{sb2}
        \end{exercise_list}

\printAnswers

\end{document}



do not use x or e expansion on arbitrary user input. The section title can contain command that can error in such cases. Always use \protected@edef.

In addition to @UlrikeFischer's comment or use \exp_not:V \thesectionname.

Also recent policy is to prefer e over x expansion (x is mostly deprecated). So use \seq_put_right:Ne instead of :Nx.

More over you're globall assigning to a local-named variable. You should use \g_listcontent_seq, and the variable misses a module-part in its name (since yours is an answer to the OP you might use OP's user name as the module name, which is common practice around here).

@Skillmon Fixed. Why \exp_not:V should be used instead of \exp_not:N?

Because you want the value of the variable \thesectionname, hence you use V to expand it to its value, and then protect the result of that (\exp_not:n -- which is the base variant of \exp_not:V).

You got the position of \exp_not:V wrong. It should be \exp_not:N \subsection { \exp_not:V \thesectionname }.

@Skillmon Fixed again.
